# SELECT2 - Repeating options

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am having several dropdown as shown below

```
<select class="myselect2" id="emp_select1"></select>
<select class="myselect2" id="emp_select2"></select>
<select class="myselect2" id="emp_select3"></select>
```

Can we simplify code below since their options are same? (Trying not repeating)

```
$("#emp_select1").select2({
  placeholder: "Search for employee",
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: {
    url: "something.php",
    dataType: "json",
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        str: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }            
});

$("#emp_select2").select2({
  placeholder: "Search for employee",
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  ajax: {
    url: "something.php",
    dataType: "json",
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        str: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }            
});

$("#emp_select3").select2({
  ....SAME....            
});
```

I tried to change the **#emp_select1** to **.myselect2**, but it doesn't apply select2 to every dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the class again, and try to see your console for any errors.
Using the class should work fine as shown below.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<select class="myselect2" id="emp_select1"></select>
<select class="myselect2" id="emp_select2"></select>
<select class="myselect2" id="emp_select3"></select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myselect2").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for employee",
    minimumInputLength: 1  
  });
})
</script>
```